# jQuery shuffle div when clicking on image

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, shuffle

I am trying to use a button as an image, will shuffle a block of text

Sorry if this is a very basic question, I'm just having trouble applying it to my current jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some bugs in the opening and closing tags of your `.headline1` class. You first need to properly define the refresh click function by defining the id like `$('#refresh').click()`.
I assume you need something similar as your solution:

```
$(function () {
 $('#refresh').click(function() {
var parent = $(".headline1");
var divs = parent.children();
while (divs.length) {
       parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
     }
  });
});
```

Check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/23txte9L/1/)**.